# Lambda capture list and copying

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Copy
{
    Copy(){}
    Copy(const Copy&)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied!\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Copy copy;
    std::function<void()> func = [=]{(void)copy;};
    return 0;
}
```

And it calls copy-ctor 2 times and I want to have it only one time. I understand that I can use auto in this simplified example but I need to store it for some later use so auto is no option.
And my question: is there a way to store lambda with **=** capture list and have only one copy of the captured objects?

Comment: I'm surprised the instance gets copied, as the function you create doesn't actually get called. What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Of course there are two copies: one to copy `copy` into the lambda, and one which occurs when the lambda (which has a `Copy` member) is copied in to the `std::function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two copies: one to copy `copy` into the lambda, and one which occurs when the lambda (which has a `Copy` member) is copied in to the `std::function`.

If you want one copy and one move, you will need to make the `Copy` object be movable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Copy
{
    Copy(){}
    Copy(const Copy&)
    {
        std::cout << "Copied!\n";
    }
    Copy(Copy&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Moved!\n";
    }
};
//Prints:
//Copied!
//Moved!
int main()
{
    Copy copy;
    std::function<void()> func = [=]{(void)copy;};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this moving by standard? I mean does lambda have to have move-ctor/operator=?

Comment: @ixSci: Yes -- see  `[expr.prim.lambda]/19`: "The closure type associated with a lambda-expression has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitly-declared move constructor (12.8). [ Note: The copy/move constructor is implicitly defined in the same way as any other implicitly declared copy/move constructor would be implicitly defined. — end note ]". (Thanks for asking though, the note about `mutable` was false)

Comment: thanks Mankarse! I'm litle confused by the "may have an implicitly-declared move constructor", though. GCC and Clang have it and MSVC doesn't. And I'm not sure I can file the bug since this behavior is not forced by the standard but simply "is not forbidden"

Comment: submitted to [MS connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777256/move-ctor-in-lambda)

Comment: @ixSci: The "may" simply refers to the fact that the move constructor will only exist if all the captured objects are movable. There is no "may" for the copy constructor clause because objects that are captured by copy **must** be copyable, so the copy constructor is always available. (See `§12.8/9` and `§12.8/11` for more about implicitly declared constructors -- I believe the MSVC behaviour is non-conforming).